# How do I replace dataframe index with column values from another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I want to merge `raw_clinical_patient` and `raw_clinical_sample` dataframes.

However, the `SAMPLE_ID` column in `raw_clinical_sample` should be relabeled as `PATIENT_ID` before the merge (because it was wrongly labelled).

I want the new `PATIENT_ID` to be the index of `raw_clin`. However, my code still retain the original `PATIENT_ID`.

```
# Clinical patient info
raw_clinical_patient = pd.read_csv("./gbm_tcga/data_clinical_patient.txt", sep="\t", header=4)
raw_clinical_patient.set_index("PATIENT_ID", inplace=True)
raw_clinical_patient.sort_index()

# Clinical sample info
# Keep info only if `Patient_ID` value exists in `raw_clinical_patient`
raw_clinical_sample = pd.read_csv("./gbm_tcga/data_clinical_sample.txt", sep="\t", header=4)
raw_clinical_sample.set_index("PATIENT_ID", inplace=True)
raw_clinical_sample = raw_clinical_sample.sort_index()
raw_clinical_sample = raw_clinical_sample[raw_clinical_sample.index.isin(raw_clinical_patient.index)]


# Get the actual patient ID from the `raw_clinical_sample` dataframe
# Drop "PATIENT_ID" and rename "SAMPLE_ID" as "PATIENT_ID" and set as index
raw_clin = pd.merge(raw_clinical_patient, raw_clinical_sample, on="PATIENT_ID")
raw_clin.rename(columns={'PATIENT_ID':'PI'}, inplace=True)
raw_clin.rename(columns={'SAMPLE_ID':'PATIENT_ID'}, inplace=True)
raw_clin
```

`raw_clinical_patient` dataframe example

```
raw_clinical_patient = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0003", 2003, "WITH TUMOR", 100, 50], ["TCGA-02-0004", 2002, "WITH TUMOR", 80, 59], ["TCGA-02-0006", 2002, "WITH TUMOR", 80, 56], ["TCGA-02-0007",2002, "WITH TUMOR", 80, 40]], columns=["PATIENT_ID", 'INITIAL_PATHOLOGIC_DX_YEAR', 'TUMOR_STATUS', 'KARNOFSKY_PERFORMANCE_SCORE', 'AGE'])
```

`raw_clinical_sample` example

```
raw_clinical_sample = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0003-01", "123ebb05-33c0-441c-9549-262433b14810", "TCGA-02-0003"], ["TCGA-02-0006-01", "03c9930f-7695-419a-bf24-184be75aea63", "TCGA-02-0006"], ["TCGA-02-0007-01", "1b41259b-0cb2-4194-ba1e-352d4ae98ed1", "TCGA-02-0007"], ["TCGA-02-0009-01", "a731e84e-436f-4e4c-9012-5d68949d1d0f", "TCGA-02-0009"]], columns=['SAMPLE_ID', 'OTHER_SAMPLE_ID', 'PATIENT_ID'])
```

`raw_clin` **desired** output

```
raw_clin = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0003-01", 2003, "WITH TUMOR", 100, 50, "123ebb05-33c0-441c-9549-262433b14810"], ["TCGA-02-0006-01", 2002, "WITH TUMOR", 80, 54, "03c9930f-7695-419a-bf24-184be75aea63"], ["TCGA-02-0007-01", 2002, "WITH TUMOR", 80, 56, "1b41259b-0cb2-4194-ba1e-352d4ae98ed1"]], columns=['PATIENT_ID', 'INITIAL_PATHOLOGIC_DX_YEAR', 'TUMOR_STATUS', 'KARNOFSKY_PERFORMANCE_SCORE', 'AGE', 'OTHER_SAMPLE_ID'])
```

The new index values of `raw_clin` should be:

```
TCGA-02-0003-01
TCGA-02-0006-01
TCGA-02-0007-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I'm following what you need your outputs to be but I think the following should do the trick:

```
raw_clin = (
    raw_clinical_patient.merge(raw_clinical_sample, on='PATIENT_ID',how='left')
    .dropna()
    .set_index('PATIENT_ID')
    # edit: also rename sample id:
    .rename({'SAMPLE_ID': 'PATIENT_ID'}, axis=1)

 
)
```

This gives the output:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'INITIAL_PATHOLOGIC_DX_YEAR': {'TCGA-02-0003': 2003,
  'TCGA-02-0006': 2002,
  'TCGA-02-0007': 2002},
 'TUMOR_STATUS': {'TCGA-02-0003': 'WITH TUMOR',
  'TCGA-02-0006': 'WITH TUMOR',
  'TCGA-02-0007': 'WITH TUMOR'},
 'KARNOFSKY_PERFORMANCE_SCORE': {'TCGA-02-0003': 100,
  'TCGA-02-0006': 80,
  'TCGA-02-0007': 80},
 'AGE': {'TCGA-02-0003': 50, 'TCGA-02-0006': 56, 'TCGA-02-0007': 40},
 'SAMPLE_ID': {'TCGA-02-0003': 'TCGA-02-0003-01',
  'TCGA-02-0006': 'TCGA-02-0006-01',
  'TCGA-02-0007': 'TCGA-02-0007-01'},
 'OTHER_SAMPLE_ID': {'TCGA-02-0003': '123ebb05-33c0-441c-9549-262433b14810',
  'TCGA-02-0006': '03c9930f-7695-419a-bf24-184be75aea63',
  'TCGA-02-0007': '1b41259b-0cb2-4194-ba1e-352d4ae98ed1'}}
)
```

which you can copy and print to check for correctness.